# Loading Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo fails

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am following the example code at https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-sql-powershell-level-9-objects-for-everyone

The first line is:

```
Add-Type –AssemblyName “Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91”
```

This results in:

```
Add-Type: C:\src\sql\sql-objects-001.ps1:1
Line |
   1 |  Add-Type -AssemblyName “Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=12.0.0.0, Cu …
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Cannot find path 'C:\src\sql\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll' because it does not exist.
```

It clearly did not find the .dll file in the current working directory. Does Add-Type always require a fully qualified path?

There are -many- possibilities on my system to find the specified .dll file. Does the correct .dll file need to be matched in some way to the SQL Server version (2016, 2019, 2022) to be accessed?

```
PS C:\> (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Filter 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).FullName
C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\resources\app\extensions\mssql\sqltoolsservice\Windows\4.4.1.5\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18226\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18226\coreclr\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19\Common7\IDE\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 19\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\160\Binn\150References\SMO\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.DLL
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSAS\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\130\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\140\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLCommon\150\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\src\dbatools\bin\smo\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\src\dbatools\bin\smo\coreclr\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\.nuget\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.sqlmanagementobjects\150.18118.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\.nuget\packages\microsoft.sqlserver.sqlmanagementobjects\150.18118.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\.vscode\extensions\ms-mssql.mssql-1.18.0\sqltoolsservice\4.5.1.6\Windows\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.1.95\bin\smo\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.1.95\bin\smo\coreclr\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18256\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18256\coreclr\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.0.113\bin\smo\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\dbatools\1.0.113\bin\smo\coreclr\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18218\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18218\coreclr\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18245\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Users\lit\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer\21.1.18245\coreclr\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo\13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll
```

Comment: *"Does the correct .dll file need to be matched in some way to the SQL Server version"*  Yes, the article states that: *"If you have SQL 2008R2 installed, change the 12.0.0.0 to 10.0.0.0 and if you have SQL 2012 then change it to 11.0.0.0 and leave it for SQL 2014"*

Comment: Worth noting that article is "Level 9" of the [stairway](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairways/stairway-to-sql-powershell); there are assumptions you've "completed" the prior "levels".

Comment: You are using code from 2014.  I would use Invoke-SQL which does not require specifying version of obsolete libraries.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?force_isolation=true&view=sqlserver-ps